# How do I kill a processes running a given executable?

Tags: powershell, process, kill

I want to kill a job.  First, I need it's process Id, so I execute:

```
get-process
```

And I get a boatload of processes.  OK, I just want one particular process, so I use:

```
get-process | select-string -pattern "nginx"
```

Which gives me this object:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process (nginx)
```

What do I do with this?  How can I pretty print this to give me the same line of output I'm getting when I ask for all the processes?  I basically just want this when I grep for a given executing process:

```
166      11     2436       8244       0.13  24196   1 nginx
```

Comment: Please don't use the term "job" when you mean process. This is not only misleading, but also attracts wrong search results, when people are looking for something about PowerShell Jobs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select-String` is probably not the hammer you wanna use for this particular nail (see below) :-)

`Get-Process` has a `-Name` parameter that takes a wildcard:

```
Get-Process -Name nginx
# or
Get-Process -Name *nginx*
```

To kill the process, either call `Kill()` directly on the object:

```
$nginxProcess = Get-Process nginx |Select -First 1
$nginxProcess.Kill()
```

... or simply pipe the process instances to `Stop-Process`:

```
Get-Process -Name nginx |Stop-Process
```

As you can see, we never actually need to locate or pass the process id - the `Process` object already has that information embedded in it, and the `*-Process` cmdlets are designed to work *in concert* - PowerShell is all about command *composition*, and this is an example of it.

That being said, `Stop-Process` is also perfectly capable of killing processes by name alone:

```
Stop-Process -Name nginx
```

---

### How did I know the `*-Process` cmdlets had a `-Name` parameter?

Apart from reading the [help files and documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?) (I get it, *I don't want to read anything either unless I absolutely have to* ;-)), a quick way to learn about the parameters exposed by a cmdlet is by running `Get-Command <commandName> -Syntax`:

```
PS ~> Get-Command Stop-Process -Syntax

Stop-Process [-Id] <int[]> [-PassThru] [-Force] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]

Stop-Process -Name <string[]> [-PassThru] [-Force] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]

Stop-Process [-InputObject] <Process[]> [-PassThru] [-Force] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
```

The output shows us 3 distinct "parameter sets" (combinations of parameter input accepted by the command), and the required and optional arguments we can pass to it.

---

### What's wrong with `Select-String`?

The `Select-String` cmdlet is the PowerShell cognate to `grep` - it takes some input, and performs regular expression matching against it based on whatever pattern you give it.

But `grep` is only useful when you're operating on *strings* - and as you've already found, `Get-Process` returns structured .NET objects, not flat strings.

Instead, the PowerShell-idiomatic approach is to *filter* the data, using the `Where-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object Name -like '*nginx*'
```

Here, we instruct `Where-Object` to only let through object that have a `Name` property, the value of which must satisfy the wildcard pattern `*nginx*`.

`Where-Object` also supports *arbitrary filter expressions*, by accepting a scriptblock - PowerShell will assign the current pipeline object being evaluated to `$_` (and `$PSItem`):

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*nginx*' }
```

... which you can extend to whatever degree you need:

```
# Only let them through if a specific user is executing
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*nginx*' -and $env:USERNAME -ne 'Quarkly'}
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that while `Select-String` is the wrong cmdlet to use in the OP's context, `Where-Object` would have been a better alternative given that context. Still not as good of a solution as you provided, but useful information to help them become a better scripter in general.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Good point, agreed. I've updated the answer

Comment: Yes, the suggestion to use **Where-Object** was enlightening.